# How to match a string and white space in R

Tags: regex, r, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe with columns having values like:

"Average 18.24" "Error 23.34". My objective is to replace the text and following space from these. in R. Can any body help me with a regex pattern to do this?

I am able to successfully do this using the [A-Z]. But i am not able to combine the white space. [A-Z][[:space:]] no luck. 
Your help is appreciated.

Comment: As you can see, you failed because `[A-Z]` does not match lowercase letters, and `[A-Z]` without a `+` or `*` matches 1 symbol. With `+` after it, it matches 1 or more letters, with `*` it matches 0 or more.

Comment: Thank you this helps. My knowledge on Regex is primitive.

Comment: Glad [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38392533/3832970) helped, please  consider accepting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can use `sub`.  Use the pattern `\\D+` to match all non-numeric characters and then use `''` in the replacement to remove those.

```
sub("\\D+", '', v2)
#[1] "18.24" "23.34"
```

Or match one or more word characters followed by one or more space and replace with `''`.

```
 sub("\\w+\\s+", "", v2)
 #[1] "18.24" "23.34"
```

Or if we are using `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
word(v2, 2)
#[1] "18.24" "23.34"
```

#### data

```
v2 <- c("Average 18.24" ,"Error 23.34")
```

Comment: love the `word()` sol ... :)

Comment: Thank you for explanation. It helped me to fix my error

Answer (score 12):

You can use a quantifier and add `a-z` to the pattern (and the `^` anchor)

You can use

```
"^\\S+\\s+"
"^[a-zA-Z]+[[:space:]]+"
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nW7cC9/1)

[*R* demo](https://ideone.com/CAFVTe):

```
> b <- c("Average 18.24", "Error 23.34")
> sub("^[A-Za-z]+[[:space:]]+", "", b)
> ## or sub("^\\S+\\s+", "", b)
[1] "18.24" "23.34"
```

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Za-z]+` - one or more letters (replace with `\\S+` to match 1 or more non-whitespaces)
- `[[:space:]]+` - 1+ whitespaces (or `\\s+` will match 1 or more whitespaces)